# Flutter Serverpod returns 400 error on sample project

Tags: flutter, 400-bad-request, serverpod

I'm newly learning [Serverpod](https://serverpod.dev/) version 0.9.21 as my backend, first I changed the `Client` address from `http://localhost:8080/` to `http://10.0.2.2:8080/` so the `SocketException` error had gone on the emulator and now the sample app (say hello) works correctly. **The Problem** is my code faces Error **400** with no `errorMessage`, Also I've added the tables and checked the database, and everything looks fine.

After creating the project, I added `Province` Protocol inside the test_server package:

```
class: Province
table: province
fields:
  name: String
  isEnabled: bool
```

Then added the `province_endpoint`:

```
import 'package:serverpod/serverpod.dart';
import '../generated/protocol.dart';

class ProvinceEndpoint extends Endpoint {
  Future<bool> addProvince(Session session, Province province) async {
    await Province.insert(session, province);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then run `serverpod generate` and start the docker and the server as tutorials are mentioning.

And finally the test_flutter `main.dart`:

```
import 'package:back_client/back_client.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:serverpod_flutter/serverpod_flutter.dart';

var client = Client('http://10.0.2.2:8080/')
  ..connectivityMonitor = FlutterConnectivityMonitor();

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final _nameController = TextEditingController(text: "name1");
  String result = "here";

  addProvince() async {
    final province = Province(name: _nameController.text, isEnabled: true);
    client.province.addProvince(province).then((value) {
      if (value) {
        setState(() {
          result = "Done adding ${_nameController.text} province";
        });
      } else {
        result = "Nashod!";
      }
    }).catchError((onError) {
      final error = (onError is ServerpodClientException)
          ? "${onError.message} ${onError.statusCode}"
          : "Error ";
      setState(() {
        result = error;
      });
    }).whenComplete(() {
      print("done");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            controller: _nameController,
          ),
          Text(
            result,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3,
          )
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: addProvinces,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a noob in Backend stuff, I didn't **restart** the docker and server after developing the endpoint! As flutter has hot-reload it made me a little bit lazy!
After development, in the terminal that serverpod is running, press `Ctrl + C` to close its processes, then run `docker-compose up --build --detach && dart bin/main.dart`